# Pass pure lua object to C function and get value

Tags: c++, c, lua

In Lua Code

```
Test = {}
function Test:new()
  local obj = {}
  setmetatable(obj, self)
  self.__index = self
  return obj
end
local a = Test:new()
a.ID = "abc123"
callCfunc(a)
```

In C Code

```
int callCfunc(lua_State * l)
{
   void* obj = lua_topointer(l, 1);            //I hope get lua's a variable
   lua_pushlightuserdata(l, obj);   
   lua_getfield(l, 1, "ID");
   std::string id = lua_tostring(l, 1);        //I hoe get the value "abc123"
   ...
   return 0;
}
```

But My C result is

```
id = null
```

Why? How to modify code to work fine ? 
PS: I don't hope create C Test Class mapping to lua

==== update1 ==== 
In addition, I have added the test code to confirm correct incoming parameters.

```
int callCfunc(lua_State * l)
{
   std::string typeName = lua_typename(l, lua_type(l, 1));    // the typeName=="table"
   void* obj = lua_topointer(l, 1);            //I hope get lua's a variable
   lua_pushlightuserdata(l, obj);   
   lua_getfield(l, 1, "ID");
   std::string id = lua_tostring(l, 1);        //I hoe get the value "abc123"
   ...
   return 0;
}
```

the result

```
typeName == "table"
```

so incoming parameter type is Correct

Comment: Aren't objects indexed from 0? Should not all the 1s be zeroes instead?

Comment: You may like to accept some of your answers - you'll get more responses. 0% accept is less than acceptable :-)

Comment: In addition, I have added the test code to confirm correct incoming parameters. std::string typeName = lua_typename(l, lua_type(l, 1));  the result typeName == "table"  so incoming parameter type is Correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the reason 
Correct c code should is ... 
In C Code

```
int callCfunc(lua_State * l)
{
   lua_getfield(l, 1, "ID");
   std::string id = lua_tostring(l, -1);        //-1
   ...
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: How to close the question? I don't find the close menu.

Comment: use lua_istable() to check the input parameter is a table - http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_istable. To close the question just accept an answer - if your's then you'll have to wait a while I think.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this - haven't tested sorry - don't have a compiler handy

Input is the table from lua on top of the stack, so getfield(l,1, "ID") should get the field ID from the table at the top of the stack - which in this case is your input table. It then pushes the result to the top of the stack

```
int callCfunc(lua_State * l)
{
   lua_getfield(l, 1, "ID");
   std::string id = lua_tostring(l, 1);        //I hoe get the value "abc123"
   ...
   return 0;
}
```